Power estimate for an interaction term in factorial design
I am trying to estimate power for a factorial design (2x2).
My initial approach was to estimate pair-wise minimum detectable effect sizes : i.e., if I know sample size, allocation to each group and variance in outcome I estimate (minimum detectable effect size) MDEs for each treatment vs the "pure control".
I have come across literature, notably here, which suggest that this is not a good approach to estimate the power for the interaction term (i.e., where both groups get treatment). But I can't figure out what an appropriate formula for MDE would be in this case. Has anyone come across this issue ?
Thanks

With a 2-way ANOVA you want to evaluate the interaction between the two treatments. So which minimum detectable effect (MDE) do you care about? Is it the MDE of that interaction? You need to go beyond the individual treatment-versus-control estimates to deal with the interactions.
Simulation provides the flexibility to deal with complex designs. The R Superpower package is designed primarily to simplify simulations of ANOVA designs for power estimates. The package also, however, provides an analytic solution, the power_twoway_between() function, that might work for your situation. You could inspect the open-source code to see the details of the calculation.
